# how to get less to show tabs as tabs?

Tags: less, whitespace

When I view data with tabs in `less`, tab characters are expanded to spaces. If I then copy them directly out of my terminal using ctrl-c, they copy as spaces. On the other hand, `more` preserves tab characters, as do many other commands like `tail` and `head`. Is there any way to get `less` to keep tabs intact?

`-r` doesn't seem to have any effect even when combined with `-U`, which claims to treat tabs as control characters. I don't see any other relevant options for `less`.

Comment: I think that may depend on the terminal too, at least I don't remember ever being able to copy tabs as anything other than spaces from a terminal emulator (but that might also be because I usually have an ssh connection in between). So, what terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @ilkkachu I am using Terminal in Ubuntu. It renders tabs as tabs: I can copy them intact from `more`, `tail`, `head`, etc. And tabs are preserved in ssh sessions. I doubt the terminal is part of the problem.

Comment: Ok! I can try to test that if no-one else comes with a solution.

Comment: `less -U filename` works for me (less 481, ubuntu, gnome terminal).  The tab characters are displayed as `^I` instead of being space-filled.

Comment: @user4556274 But `^I` is not the same as ` `. When I copy the former I get a carat followed by uppercase I. When I copy the latter I get a single tab character.

Comment: I'm not finding a code path that allows this when outputting to a terminal.  Consider this comment from `line.c` around line 940 (v487): "`if (ch == '\t') /* Expand a tab into spaces. */`.  Not definitive on its own, but showing the preference of the `less` authors.

Comment: Interestingly, if I pipe though `less` then `cat` ie `printf '>\t<' | less | cat`, it keeps the tab. (But piping through `less` alone does not)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [manpage for `less`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) appears to be misleading.

By using the `-r` and `-U` options in combination, you will prevent `less` from converting tabs to spaces as it reads lines from the input and populates its output buffer.  However, when the output buffer is written to a terminal (as opposed to being written to a file or pipe), a second conversion of tabs to spaces is effected in the `write()` call due to termio settings, contradicting behavior one might expect by reading the manpage.

If you compile `less` from source, and comment or `#ifdef` out the lines which or `XTABS`, `OXTABS`, or `TAB3` into `s.c_oflag` in `screen.c:raw_mode()` (lines 398-411 and 489 in version 487 of [`less`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/less/)), you will get a version of `less` which outputs tab characters if invoked with `-r -U`.

I could not find any existing command-line option to produce the desired behavior, although it would be easy to produce a version in which this behavior was togglable.

Using a sufficiently dumb terminal should also work.

Comment: Dumb terminal does not work for me: `export TERM=dumb` or `vt100`

Comment: For `printf '>\t<\n'`, `stty -tabs` makes the tab convert to spaces and `stty tabs` leaves it as a tab. But `less` always uses spaces either way. For me `more` always uses spaces but `cat`/`head` leave it as a tab (using MacOS).

Comment: I did compile `less` with the patch you mentioned and it worked. Now, with `git config --global core.pager "less -r -U"` I have a diff that I can copy/paste correctly ! Thanks